# play framework file upload

Tags: java, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to add file uploading handling in play framework app to existing form with text field.
 [According to documentation,](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaFileUpload) I need to use `asMultipartFormData()` or `asRaw` method, however, it can not handle text input fields. Is it possible to use one controller for standart html form and file processing at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, just simply handle file and text input separately. For instance:

```
public Result myControllerMethod(){
  ...
  //handle input text here
  Form<MyModel> myForm = formFactory.form(MyModel.class);
  MyModel myModel = myForm.bindFromRequest().get();
  ...
  //handle file
  MultipartFormData<File> body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But actually it will be two requests? Once for form, then for file?

Comment: If the file input is part of the same form (as I understand) no, it is one request. Try to inspect it with debugger, you can see that the body contains a dataPart field (with an HashMap with all textual informations) and a file field.